# How to run unit tests?

Tags: voting, testing, codebase

I have downloaded the source code and built my node from scratch.

What command should I run in order to double check that all unit tests run fine?

In particular I am interested in running the unit test for [voting](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/merge_requests/764).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run all the tests with:

```
dune build @runtest
```

if you want particular tests you need to find their "alias name"

```
dune build @runtest_voting.sh
```

is one of them (That I found with `git grep runtest_vot` :), the file `.gitlab-ci.yml` has many examples also).

Comment: Awesome will try that. Do i need to install dune separately ?

Comment: If you have built tezos, you already have `dune`. Maybe you need to run `eval $(opam env)` for your shell to "see" it.

Answer (score 4):

One can go in the `src/proto_alpha/lib_protocol/test` and run `dune runtest`, which will execute all unit tests for the protocol alpha, including the ones for voting (those in `voting.ml`).

Another test is present in `src/bin_client/test/test_voting.sh` which tests the client commands related to voting.

All these tests are executed when one runs `make test`.